# google app script: same api with different file

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm a beginner in `google app script`. The two function in separate file id declared and it works on google debug well.

Therefore, I deploy to web application but when I connect the API and it only returns my first function (`onGet`).

Is possible like `node` or `php` that could use a different name to call another API? i.e. API/A_WEB_SERVICE . API/B_WEB_SERVICE.

Or I need to add a new project to handle my situation?

**my.js**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/my_key/exec",
  data: data,
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert('cool works.');
  }
});
```

**gs**

```
doGet(){} // in my first file.

doDebug(){} // in my second file.
```

Comment: I find the way that adds method variable in parameter and mapping to method function!

Comment: What's your question? As stated, it is not clear what problems you are having with the code you have written. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tehhowch hi, I found the solution in my first comment.

Comment: if your question is resolved, consider adding the solution as a high quality answer, if you think it can be useful to others. Otherwise consider deleting the question if you feel the solution is not useful to others.